# How to define a generic function that takes a function that converts a slice to an iterator

Tags: rust, lifetime

I want to write a function that process some slices in different order, so I decided to write a function that is generic over the iterating order, something like:

```rust
fn foo<'a, I: Iterator<Item = &'a mut i32>>(make_iter: impl Fn(&'a mut [i32]) -> I) {
    let mut data = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    make_iter(&mut data);
}

fn main() {
    foo(|x| x.iter_mut());
    foo(|x| x.iter_mut().rev());
}
```

This causes “borrowed value does not live long enough” error.

I imagine something like

```rust
fn foo(make_iter: impl for<'a> Fn(&'a mut [i32]) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a mut i32>) {
    let mut data = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    make_iter(&mut data);
}
```

should be used, but `impl Iterator` is not allow at that position. So is there anything I can do?

Update:

The slices to to processed should be considered dynamically generated inside the `foo` function, and are dropped after processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with one solution:

```rust
use std::iter::Rev;
use std::slice::IterMut;

trait MakeIter<'a> {
    type Iter: Iterator<Item = &'a mut i32>;

    fn make_iter(&mut self, slice: &'a mut [i32]) -> Self::Iter;
}

fn foo(mut make_iter: impl for<'a> MakeIter<'a>) {
    let mut data = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    make_iter.make_iter(&mut data);
}

struct Forward;

impl<'a> MakeIter<'a> for Forward {
    type Iter = IterMut<'a, i32>;

    fn make_iter(&mut self, slice: &'a mut [i32]) -> Self::Iter {
        slice.iter_mut()
    }
}

struct Backward;

impl<'a> MakeIter<'a> for Backward {
    type Iter = Rev<IterMut<'a, i32>>;

    fn make_iter(&mut self, slice: &'a mut [i32]) -> Self::Iter {
        slice.iter_mut().rev()
    }
}

fn main() {
    foo(Forward);
    foo(Backward);
}
```

But I am not sure whether it can be simplified.

**Update**

Here is a simplification:

```rust
trait MakeIter<'a> {
    type Iter: Iterator<Item = &'a mut i32>;

    fn make_iter(&mut self, slice: &'a mut [i32]) -> Self::Iter;
}

fn foo(mut make_iter: impl for<'a> MakeIter<'a>) {
    let mut data = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    make_iter.make_iter(&mut data);
}

impl<'a, F, R> MakeIter<'a> for F
where
    F: FnMut(&'a mut [i32]) -> R,
    R: Iterator<Item = &'a mut i32>,
{
    type Iter = R;

    fn make_iter(&mut self, slice: &'a mut [i32]) -> Self::Iter {
        self(slice)
    }
}

fn iter_forward(slice: &mut [i32]) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut i32> {
    slice.iter_mut()
}

fn iter_backward(slice: &mut [i32]) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut i32> {
    slice.iter_mut().rev()
}

fn main() {
    foo(iter_forward);
    foo(iter_backward);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is mostly correct. The compiled error "borrowed value does not live long enough" is due to the fact that you are defining your data inside the `foo` rather than pass it in. The error is because of the line`let mut data = [1, 2, 3, 4];`

The life time of the `data` is same as the function `foo` because it is created in the function `foo`. However, the closure's life time is longer than the variable `data` as the closure is passed in as an argument to `foo` so its lifetime is longer than `data`. When the function `foo` goes out of the scope, the `data` is dropped. Then your closure's is trying to return a reference `data` which is already dropped. This is why you have compiled error "borrowed value does not live long enough".

You can make this compile by passing the data into `foo` as an argument, in this case, you will not have the issue due to lifetime.

The below code will compile.

```rust
fn foo<'a, I: Iterator<Item = &'a mut i32>>(make_iter: impl Fn(&'a mut [i32]) -> I, data: &'a mut Vec<i32>) {
    // let mut data = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    make_iter(data);
}

fn main() {
    let mut data= vec![1,2,3,4];
    foo(|x| x.iter_mut(), &mut data);
    foo(|x| x.iter_mut().rev(), &mut data);
}
```

The rustplay ground link : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8b263451fcb01518b3f35bda8485af9c

---

Update: Sry to misunderstand your requirements. I was trying to come out a clean way to write this, but the best I can come up with is using `Box<dyn` to do. I know there are runtime cost for `Box<dyn...`, but I can't come out a better way using `impl Iterator`

The implementation using `Box<dyn ...` is

```rust
fn foo<F>(make_iter: F) where for<'a> F: Fn(&'a mut [i32])->Box<dyn Iterator<Item=&'a mut i32>+'a>{
    let mut data = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    make_iter(&mut data);
}


fn main() {
    foo(|x| Box::new(x.iter_mut()));
    foo(|x| Box::new(x.iter_mut().rev()));
}
```

Comment: There are several slices to be processed. Those slices are short lived, dynamically generated in the `foo` function, and are dropped after processing, it is not possible to generate them outside of the function.